# IBM Connections Customization: Add custom jsp containing navigation, header, footer

Tags: ibm-connections

We're currently adding a custom jsp file, which can be browsed by clicking a link in the (customized) navigation bar.

Said new page should look like a "native" page in connections and therefore of course contain headers, navigation, footers like any other page in IBM Connections. We added a `<jsp:include>` for the header.jsp file, which results in the links being shown in the resulting html. However, the styles and js are still missing.

To get around this, we included `<lc-ui:dojo include="${javascriptModuleInclude}" />` into our page, since we observed this in other (native) connections jsp files. Sadly, that did not work out at all.

We can't find any help on this in the customization Documentations and the only thread in the official Connections Forum did not receive an answer http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcforum.nsf/d6091795dfaa5b1185256a7a0048a2d0/b9b5303e92c5676d85257c040046ff8c?OpenDocument

Does anyone have insights or even a hint were to look for a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Customization Dir is located on your system in a directory like /local/IBM/Connections/data/shared/customization 
customizationDir/themes/applications/profiles.css

override the css values for lotusPostDetails, you can check exactly what renders the css *rules wise in Firebug, and selectively override

Learn more info at
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/connections/4.5.0/doc/accessible/admin/en_us/acc_p4.html 
Subtopic... Determining where to save your customizations

You will need to restart the Connections Server before the customizations take effect.

you can add common.css as well.

also you can reference oneui as well http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/index.htm

Comment: hanks Paul. I have already read about customization and know where to put the files. Actually we already <jsp:include> ed our own jsp into an existing (and customized) connections jsp, as I mentioned. The real challenge remains to have a new custom jsp and find a way to embed the "frame" elements that Connections has on every page (like the navigation and search). I will look into the oneui reference, it might provide the insight we need there...

Comment: Sadly, we couldn't use this to solve our problem. We don't seem to find a way to include the whole navigation header and its functionality into our page. Especially the required scripts are not to be found, leaving us with a now nice looking but disfunctional navigation bar :-(

Comment: wait so you wanted to add it to your jsp page?   all you have to do is include the CSS from Connections, and the main classes from the lotus oneui, as documented above.

Comment: you should reference this link - http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/guidelines/page.htm

Answer (score 0):

The bare minimum dependencies required to make the `<lc-ui:dojo>` tag work in a third party JSP page are:

```
lc.util.base-3.0.jar
lc.util.web-3.0.jar
lc.config.svc-1.1.jar
com.ibm.connections.directory.services.jar
```

Please keep in mind that this is not a supported use case — as you pointed out, you're reverse engineering native Connections JSP files. The Connections banner will probably be offered as a reusable UI component through the [SBT](https://www.ibmdw.net/social/) in the near future.

Comment: Great, thanks Claudio! We managed to get things somewhat working, doing more reverse engineering supported by folks from IBM Germany. For showcasing at Connect we should be safe, but once we're rounding of for the productive version, I will look into this more closely or (even better) see if the SBT (which we already use and love!) will have this included.